# what effect does changing the data type of an existing indexed field have on the index?

Tags: mysql

I have a few MySQL tables and I want to change the data type of some of the existing fields. The fields already have some single and multi-column indexes on them (all of which are type = "Normal").

I would like to know if changing the data types of any fields included in the existing indexes will have any effect on those indexes? Do I need to remove and re-create them for example or does MySQL handle that automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the data type of a column causes a *table restructure*, which will have the side-effect of rebuilding all indexes for the table (not only those referencing the column you altered, but *all* indexes in that table).

You don't need to drop or recreate the indexes yourself; it's already done by the time the ALTER TABLE finishes.